# Duplicate entry 'SP-10' for key 'PRIMARY' mySQL on auto generating ID java

Tags: java, mysql

I am generating the user IDs(for a table) using java. When I am sort it by descending order, it goes like this.
:

[image: mysql]

I am using following code to get the next user ID:

```
String tempStID = studentBO.getLastID();
if (tempStID.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            lblStID.setText("SS-" + 1);
        } else {
            String[] array = tempStID.split("-");
            int tempNumber = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            int finalizeOrderId = tempNumber + 1;
            lblStID.setText("SS-" + finalizeOrderId);
        }
```

As this code getting the SS-9 as the last ID it generate SS-10 for the next ID, but as it is already there it giving me the duplicate entry error.

[image: error]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Besides the wrong order numeric vs. alphabetical the recipe "last ID + 1" could with concurrent call result in twice the same ID. Can you not use the DB provided auto-generated sequences?

Comment: your code would work fine if your getLastID to actually got the last id, e.g. `select pID from yourtablename order by -substring_index(pID,'-') limit 1`.  that would not be very efficient though.  I suggest you ditch the SP- prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Would not recommend using "SP-" in your primary key. Would recommend an arbitrary id that auto increments. See these docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pID VARCHAR(20),
    ... -- other columns
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When you create a new user, you can then update the pID to be "SP-" + generated_id

Tables in MySQL maintain insertion order. If you can guarantee that pID will not be updated after being inserted the first time, you can still get the correct lastId by selecting the last element of the unsorted table. Don't sort, as it's sorting alphabetically, not numerically.